# installing ubuntu through network

Tags: ubuntu

i want to install ubuntu ver 9.04 through network...
how can it be done??

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question is very vague. Canonical's wiki has instructions for many scenarios here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/WindowsServerNetboot

Comment: +1 good answer when windows is your starting point.  I didn't know they had that written up.

Answer (score 0):

Carls answer is good.  There is also a Step-by-step tutorial from [Canonical](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LocalNet) for a LocalNet if Linux is your starting point, which should get you going.  A list of all of the network install options is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Server%20and%20network%20installations).